# sObject type 'RemoteProxy' is not supported

Tags: api, profile, permission-sets, tooling-api, remote-site-settings

I'm having: "sObject type 'RemoteProxy' is not supported." when I try to do an API call. I'm sure it is a profile permission issue. RemoteProxy relates to 'Remote Site Settings'. On the profile page, there is nothing related specifically to 'Remote Site Settings' or something with those words.

What specific checkbox do I have to check in order to enable a user to query Remote Site Settings?

By the way: Use Tooling API must be checked in the Developer Console. I'm having the same issue if I run in through Workbench.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The user must have the "View All Data" permission either on the Profile or a Permission Set. Note that this will allow the user to query every record in the database for every object in the database.

Comment: I enabled "View All Data" and still having the same issue!